# IE throwing "Unspecified Error" with AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

Here is an example of my code:

```
function blah()
{
  var xmlHttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200 && xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
      alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?_=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
  xmlHttp.send();
}
```

It seems to work find in Chrome but IE8 throws an "Unsepcified Error" on the if status = 200 and readyState = 4 line.

Oddly, though, the alert does give the response from the php page.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe checking status if readyState != 4 causes the error in IE?

Try

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
```

Comment: Thanks, This works. If I check status first, and readyState second, I get an error. If I check it the other way around I don't. Why does this happen?

Comment: This is how && operator works. If first condition is false, the second isn't checked, and no error is raised

Comment: I know how && works, but this doesn't make sense. xmlHttp.status is always 200, and the readyState goes from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4. I still don't see why my code generates an error?

Comment: xmlHttp.status is status code of server response. We get server response only when readyState becomes 4. Before that, we have no response and status has no sense. In Firefox it returns 0, in IE it causes an error